# How to access environment variables from `npm start`?

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

I have set up an environment variable (on OSX):

```
export npm_package_config_test_user=user42
```

and a javascript file:

```
-- index.js --
console.log(process.env.npm_package_config_test_user);
```

which if I run like `node index.js` provides me with the expected answer.  now, with this definition in the `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

I can do: `npm start` but when I do my environment variable value comes back as `undefined`.

so 2 questions:

1) why? and
2) what do I need to set up so I can pick up the value correctly?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

so what I found is that *npm* clears the `npm_package_*` space before use, so I set the variable and it wipes it out when it runs.  however, this works:

```
export test_user=user42
```